# Is there any way to go back to initial keywords information in CVS..?

Tags: cvs, version-control-keywords

I am facing an issue with keywords in CVS.

The issue is

we checked out one file a.c , from linux 2.6.28 ( linux.org). 
Then checked in the file to our CVS server. Multiple people have have checked in the file a.c

Now when I am checking out , I can see that the keywords are changed
& it shows the name of the last person who have checked in that file.
I have tried with CVS -ko flag, which will only able to go back to just previous check in detail.

So is there any way to replace the current CVS keyword information with the original one, that is the first checked in file's cvs keyword information.

[ by cvs -kk, we can disable the keyword expansion, but it will remove the 
original authors information also. ]